# How do I prove that: $E[Var(E [Y| X, C ]| C)] = E[(Y-E[Y|X,C])^2] - E[(Y - E[Y|C])^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, variance

Given random variables Y, X, and C how do we prove the following:
$E[Var(E [Y| X, C ]| C)] = E[(Y-E[Y|X,C])^2] - E[(Y - E[Y|C])^2]$. This property is the crux of the following paper: https://aclanthology.org/N18-1146.pdf which I am trying to understand.

From Wikipedia's article on [total variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance), I can see the following decomposition:
$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}(Y\mid X, C)] + \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{E}[Y\mid X,C]\mid C)] + \operatorname{Var}(\operatorname{E}[Y\mid C])$, but don't yet see how it is equal to $E[(Y-E[Y|X,C])^2] - E[(Y - E[Y|C])^2]$

Comment: It seems there's a sign error in the paper.  The expectation of the conditional variance is non-negative, but the conditional variance will shrink, not grow, with more information, making the right-hand side non-positive.  I've posted one way to deduce the corrected identity from the law of total conditional variance as an answer.

Comment: It seems that when they applied this formula, at least in section 4, they used the correct version, so it really is just a typo in section 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the law of total conditional variance,
$$\operatorname{Var}(Y|C) = E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|X,C)|C] + \operatorname{Var}(E[Y|X,C]|C).$$
Apply the expectation and simplify using the law of total expectation:
$$E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|C)] = E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|X,C)] + E[\operatorname{Var}(E[Y|X,C]|C)]$$
Now just rearrange:
$$E[\operatorname{Var}(E[Y|X,C]|C)] = E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|C)] - E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|X,C)]$$
which differs from what you've written by a sign.

Comment: Thank you! I see the trick is to decompose Var(Y|C) rather than Var(Y).

Comment: Thinking about this more deeply, I wanted a quick clarification on the probability spaces the expectation were over in the equation you get after simplifying using the law of total expectation:
It is clear that Expection of Var(Y|C) is over C and thus yield a scalar. The third term's expectation is also over C and yields a scalar. However for the second term, E(Var(Y|X,C)] is the expectation over both X and C since Var(Y|X,C) is a function of both X and C? Thanks!

Comment: @vkmv I'm not sure I understand your question.  $Y,X,C$ are defined in the same probability space since they're real measurements, so all the expectations are done in this probability space.  If they weren't defined on the same probability space, something like $\operatorname{Var}(Y|X,C)$ would be meaningless.

Comment: If you're just asking whether we can take expectations with respect to distributions, then yes, the expectation in $E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|C)]$ could be evaluated with respect to the distribution of $C$ and the expectation in $E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|X,C)]$ could be evaluated with respect to the joint distribution of $X,C$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I meant to ask with respect to which distributions the expectations were taken over and your second comment confirmed my understanding! Thanks!